# How do I make Qt graphs appear in the same window?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am working in Qt in my program. I have a widget window and I have placed a button and a list box in it. Then I have made a class called myplot which graph plotting is done. Then in my button event handler I have called the object of myplot

```
 myplot * p1 = new myplot(session,session ,24, "session"); // send arrays in argument containing the data to be plot 
    p1->show();
    myplot * p2 = new myplot(payload,payload ,24, "payload"); // send arrays in argument containing the data to be plot 
    p2->show();
```

It is working fine as my graph appear in new window, but what I want is that graphs should appear in my mainwidget window.

What I did next was to remove the title bar of my graphs window I wrote this
Qt Code:

```
p1->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
p2->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Now

1) what should I do to place and append the graphs window in my main window? Also when I close main window my graph window should close.
2) when I select an other value from the list box and click button my old graph disappear and new should appear

i drag and droped a verticlalayout then write

```
ui->verticalLayout->addChildWidget(p1);
```

but got an error

/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qlayout.h:191: error: ‘void QLayout::addChildWidget(QWidget*)’ is protected

then i draaged and droped a scrollarea and wrote

```
myplot * p1 = new myplot(session,session ,24, "session");
p1->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
ui->scrollArea->addScrollBarWidget(p1,0);
p1->show();
```

my graphs stopped appearing kindly guide me am i doing it wrong or what the right way

Comment: Use addWidget(), not addChildWidget(). It's clearly stated in the docs

Comment: In future, if you have a new question, instead of modifying an old one (so that all of the answers become wrong and out of date) perhaps you could ask a new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `myplot` is a childclass of QWidget. So you can just define a layout on your main window (e.g. using `QHBoxLayout`), and add those two widgets to it. This will cause them to be drawn inside the mainwindow. Also make sure that you pass the main window as the QWidget parent of the plots.

For replacing the plots, you can either remove the old plots from the layout and add new ones. But I would prefer to make the plots members of your main window and include some update method that would redraw with the new data

Comment: sir kindly look at the changes in my question

Answer (score 0):

When you call `show` on widgets with no parent like that, it automatically gets wrapped in a window. What you should do is create one widget and add the graphs to it's layout. See [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html) examples, and section about dock widgets if that's what you want.

Comment: sir kindly look at the changes in my question

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need to worry about the window they are appearing in, it is only appearing because they have no other parent.

What you need to do is to specify a parent widget when you construct them.

(This answer is based on the assumption that your plots are also QWidgets, if you could mention what class they actually are and perhaps link to the documentation it would really help us to answer you.)